# Overriding adminhtml form container

Tags: magento-1.8, adminhtml, overrides

I want to override the form container in import section of admin. here is my config.xml :

```
<global>
     <blocks>
         <editimport>
             <class>Company_Editimport_Block</class>
         </editimport>
         <adminhtml>
             <rewrite>
                 <import_edit>Company_Editimport_Block_Adminhtml_Import_Edit</import_edit>
             </rewrite>
         </adminhtml>
     </blocks>
 </global>
```

and also in **Company/Editimport/Block/Adminhtml/Import/Edit.php** I have:

```
 class Company_Editimport_Block_Adminhtml_Import_Edit extends
 Mage_ImportExport_Block_Adminhtml_Import_Edit {
     public function getHeaderText()
     { // changing the header of page
         return Mage::helper('importexport')->__('check if it changes');
     }
 }
```

It does not work, I checked all things for thousand times, What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely need to override the container class (`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container`) itself, and be sure to define a unique block name or else it won't initiate, see:

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php#L86-L94

You can also try to use an observer instead of rewriting, there is an event:  `adminhtml_widget_container_html_before` in the container class you could also observe as a cleaner approach.